# Parsing xlsx file using 'roo' gem, Load Error: can not load zip/zipfilesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

On Ubuntu machine, following code works fine,

My HTML code, here am passing xslx file for parsing,

```
<form method="post" action="/home/parse_xlsx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Upload XSLX File <input type="file" name="xlsx_file" id="xlsx_file"  />
   <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

My controller method,

```
def parse_xlsx
      xlsxFile = params[:xlsx_file]
      prefix_tmp_path = xlsxFile.path
      filename = xlsxFile.original_filename

      directory = "public/"
      path = File.join(directory, filename)
      File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(xlsxFile.read) }

      require 'roo'
      s = Roo::Excelx.new(path)
      for i in 2..s.count
       puts s.cell(i,1) 
      end
  end
```

But on windows machine it gives me following error. `'rubyzip'` gem is also included.

```
Load Error: can not load zip/zipfilesystem
```

Please suggest some solution..

Comment: please use ruby zip <1.0.0 version in your gemfile add `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'`

Comment: Yes I have included gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0' and it is giving me same error.

Comment: what is your rubyzip version use `bundle show rubyzip`

Comment: Yes it is `rubyzip-0.9.9`

Comment: try once `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0', require: 'zip/zip'`

Comment: Hey thanks :) after restarting my server it works with `gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'`

Comment: can I post it and please vote me up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use ruby zip <1.0.0 version in your Gemfile add

```
gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
```

Please restart after bundle install